# Magento 2 updated_at for products not updated

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2.2 and when a product is updated through the product edit dialogue, it updates the updated_at field.

[image]

But when the same is updated through the product list view, where multiple products could be updated, like enable/disable products, it is not changing the updated_at field.

[image: product updated from list view]

I would like to know when a product has changed from the last sync time.  This makes it harder to find the product as some edits are not updating the time accurately.

Comment: When you edit, Product is saved successfully?.

Comment: If the product saved successfully, then run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` and check.

Comment: the changes are reflecting fine.  Just the updated_at time is not changed when I do bulk update.

Comment: For updated_at time, Please open your database `catalog_product_entity` table structure and check type of `updated_at`. Please check its  `timestamp` or not?.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I dont see the updated_at being updated at all times.  This is not reliable and is updated only on a direct product update (through the edit function).

Either that was the design goal or this is a grave bug.  I tried upgrading and testing to various magento versions and could confirm this behavior.  Leaving this as the answer so that any one who have the same question, does not waste time any further.